# Accessing global Variables in Android

Tags: android, global-variables

I have a class file which extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback which is saved as myView.java

```
public class myView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

Now i got another java file GlobalVar.java which is like this

```
import android.app.Application;

class GlobalVar extends Application {

private int touchCount;

public int getCount()
  {
  return touchCount;
  }

public void setCount(int tCount)
  {
  touchCount = tCount;
  }
}
```

Inside myView class(myView.java) there is a function onTouchEvent

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
   }
```

Now what i want is to set the the global Variable touchCount to pointCount.
And i tried like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    GlobalVar tcount = ((GlobalVar)getApplicationWindowToken());
tcount.setCount(pointerCount);
  }
```

And this is giving me error.So how can i set the global variable value inside this myView class file???

Application portion of manifest file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MyViewActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<application android:name=".GlobalVar"  android:icon="@drawable/icon"                 android:label="@string/app_name">
</application>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May be you'll need a some singleton class which will hold all you variables?

```
public class GlobalVar {

    public int getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }

    public void setMyVar(int myVar) {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }

    private int myVar = 0;
    private static GlobalVar instance;

    static {
        instance = new GlobalVar();
    }

    private GlobalVar() {
    }

    public static GlobalVar getInstance() {
        return GlobalVar.instance;
    }

}
```

Usage pattern:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    GlobalVar.getInstance().setMyVar(pointerCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
   GlobalVar gv = (GlobalVar) getContext.getApplicationContext();
   gv.setCount(pointerCount);
   }
```

What you are doing fails because the object returned by that method isn't the Application object.
I should also mention that you need to register the name of your custom Application class in the manifest using android:name="GlobalVar" tag in your Application node.

Comment: I have tried this. This too giving error. I have edited my first post and added the manifest file.Is that one ok??

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Example:

```
// Have a SharedPreferences class 

SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   public final static String WIFI_NAME = "WIFI_NAME";
   public void setWifiName(String wifi_name) {
   Editor edit = pref.edit();
   edit.putString(WIFI_NAME, wifi_name);
   edit.commit();
}

public String getWifiName() {
   return pref.getString(WIFI_NAME, "");
}
```

Then, to access it:

```
string name = pref.getWifiName();  // GET VALUE
pref.setWifiName(name ); //SET VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
getApplicationWindowToken()
```

to:

```
getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: This will fail since he is not extending an Activity, just a SurfaceView/View. The getApplicationContext() method only belongs to Activity, not View or SurfaceView.

Comment: @Jems: OK, change `getApplicationWindowToken()` to `getContext().getApplicationContext()`, then.

Comment: this too didnt help..saying java.lang.ClassCast exception in debugger.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @LukasKnuth: If you read the "question", you will see that this is an answer to that question. This is directly addressing "And this is giving me error", by pointing out the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you set the `android:name` attribute on the `application` that contains your `Activity`?  So I would think your manifest should be:

```
<application android:name=".GlobalVar" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MyViewActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I've not tried this myself but that's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: i tried that..but that's giving error while start of the application itself..that's why i put that one separately.